# MS Access: Make Form show only records from last 48HS

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, records

I am using MS Access and I have a table called *tblLogs*, it contains all the logs and a field called *logDate*. I have created a form in which I need to show the data from *tblLogs*, but **only the records from the last two days**. My question is: what are my options?

I've been doing some research and tried making a query which retrieves the data I need from last 2 days, but after doing it I realized there wasn't an easy way to bind query content to a Control (a text box in this case). Another option that came to mind was somehow setting an automatic filter that is triggered when you open the form (don't know how to do it yet), but I don't know if that would be convenient.

So, I'm all ears guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form properties set `Filter On Load` to `Yes` and `Filter` to

```
logDate >= DateAdd('h', -48, Now())
```